# Should [clark-kent] be a synonym of [superman]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [clark-kent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clark-kent) tag has four questions and the [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman) tag has 341. Should [clark-kent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clark-kent) be a synonym of [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman), or is there value in having both tags?

The only similar situation I could find is that [tom-riddle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-riddle) is a synonym of [voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort). There is no [bruce-wayne](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bruce-wayne) tag. I didn't make any attempt to search for other secret identities to see if any of them have tags.

Comment: If people want to keep both tags, I'll write a tag wiki excerpt for [tag:clark-kent].

Comment: Woah! Spoilers, dude!

Comment: @Richard - just wait till I merge [darth-vader] and [anakin-skywalker] tags

Comment: Now we have [tag:oliver-queen] too

Comment: @AnkitSharma I guess our philosophy is, if one character tag is good, then two is better...

Comment: That's unfortunate

Comment: is superman ALWAYS clark kent? If there is an instance in which clark kent is not superman, then the tag is valid, but if the tag is currently only in use on questions where clark kent IS superman then merge em

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they should be synonyms.

Granted, one is a secret identity and there could be questions about *only* him, but a fan of Superman might not search for "Clark Kent" in order to find such a question.

Although the mods can do this work, I see the day-to-day of this as community activity. As such, I have suggested [clark-kent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clark-kent) as a synonym for [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman), since I had the requisite rep in [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman). Those who can review synonyms can [up or down vote the suggestion accordingly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/superman/synonyms).

---

As an aside, I wouldn't create secret identity tags just to match things up, but if someone feels the need when they create new questions, then we can take care of them then.

Comment: @anaranjada It's good, because it brought it to our attention, at least.

Comment: That secret identity won't be much of a secret any more if you go and make it a synonym.

Comment: Let's ping @ThaddeusHowze for help.

Comment: And @Richard maybe?

Comment: TIL: a mod's upvote on a tag synonym proposal doesn't automatically approve the synonym.

Comment: @randal'thor I know Thad and Richard have the necessary rep in the tag, off the top of my head, which in why I mentioned them.